# How to implement an interface in a delphi control

Tags: delphi, interface, custom-controls

I have read that if a class implements an interface it is now reference counted and should not manage its memory by calling `free` .

However, if you make a custom control and have it implement an interface, how do you prevent its `owner` from managing its memory?  For example when you drop it on a form at design time will the reference counting and owner memory management fight?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Controls are except from this behavior, because they do not inherit from `TInterfacedObject`.
As such they do not do reference counting, their ref count is stuck at -1 by design<sup>*)</sup>.

All controls inherit from `TComponent` which looks like this:

```
TComponent = class(TPersistent, IInterface, IInterfaceComponentReference)
```

The reference counting in TComponent looks like this:

```
function TComponent._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  if FVCLComObject = nil then Result := -1
       // -1 indicates no reference counting is taking place
  else Result := IVCLComObject(FVCLComObject)._AddRef;
end;

function TComponent._Release: Integer;
begin
  if FVCLComObject = nil then Result := -1   
  // -1 indicates no reference counting is taking place
  else Result := IVCLComObject(FVCLComObject)._Release;
end;
```

<sup>*)</sup>*The caveat being that if VCLComObject is assigned, they follow that Object's reference counting (which is normally not stuck at -1).

`VCLComObject` is nil for most components.

It is only used for component wrappers generated by the IDE to wrap COM objects.

[See: `TComponent.ComObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TComponent.ComObject)*

So you can add interfaces to your heart's content. It will work with no problems, as long as you remember to free the Component when you're done.

You can test to see if a control does reference count or not by testing:

```
DoesNotRefCount:= Supports(MyObject, IInterfaceComponentReference) 
                  and (TComponent(MyObject).VCLComObject = nil);
```

Do not call `_AddRef` on your object to test if it returns -1, because that may break objects that do use ref counting.
If your ref counted objects starts at 0 and you do an `_AddRef` followed by a `_Release` you will destroy the object, even though Delphi was just about to call `_AddRef` two instructions further down the line.

If you want to make your own objects that don't do reference counting, it may be a good idea to add a marker interface as well:

```
INoRefCounting = interface
 ['{CAD60ADF-C49A-46FB-BB5A-CC54BD22C7EB}']
end;
```

In newer Delphi's you can descent from `TSingletonImplementation` which does the dummy no-ref counting for you.
In older Delphi's descent from TObject (or TWhatever) and implement the no-ref counting like so:

```
function TMyObject.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; {stdcall;}
begin
  if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then Result := S_OK
  else Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function TMyObject._AddRef: Integer; {stdcall;}
begin
  Result := -1;
end;

function TMyObject._Release: Integer; {stdcall;}
begin
  Result := -1;
end;
```

**Final note**
If you want to make 100% sure your custom control does not do reference counting, you'll have to override the `_AddRef`/`_Release` methods to remove the conditional reference counting based on `VCLComObject`.

**Warning**
If the lifetime of your controls is short and you're still holding references to interfaces of those controls for longer then you're going to run into problems.
If you're suffering from this it might be worthwhile to add debugging code to the `_AddRef`, `_Release` and `Destroy` methods where you keep track of reference counts and signal if the refcounts reaches zero to late or too soon.

Comment: And `FVCLComObject` is usually nil for most components.  It is only used for component wrappers generated by the IDE to wrap COM objects (see `TComponent.GetComObject()`, which assigns `FVCLComObject`, though `TComponent.VCLComObject` is public so you *could* assign a COM object manually as well).

Comment: Although an interfaced object can be made to "not do reference counting" (i.e. not maintain that count) the calls to **AddRef** and **Release** will continue to occur.  More seriously, you *cannot* add interfaces and go about **Free**ing objects and be sure of no problems.  If you explicitly **Free** an object which has current interface references to it, you *will* run into serious problems when those references are **Release**d.  Better to keep a reference count and gracefully report if an object is **Free**d with a count > 0 (which you should *not* do).